# How to use an IN clause inside a SQL Update by using IBatis and Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, ibatis

Could somebody explain me how I can create a SQL Update Statement like this in IBatis (the value in the IN Clause are inside the Map):

```
UPDATE employee e
SET e.salary = 5000
WHERE e.employee_id IN (900, 800, 700);
```

I have no idea, how I can use an IN clause inside a SQL Update (inside a SQL SELECT there is no problem):

```
<update id="employeeChanging" parameterClass="Map">
   UPDATE  employee e 
   SET     e.salary= 5000                   
   WHERE   e.employee_id IN ( # configuration unclear! )
</update>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create 3 UPDATE statements like this:

```
<update id="employeeChanging" parameterClass="Map">
    <foreach item="item" collection="entries.entrySet()">
        UPDATE  employee e 
        SET     e.salary= 5000                   
        WHERE   e.employee_id = #{item.key};
    </foreach>       
</update>
```

Comment: I´m using IBatis Version < 3 and there is now foreach element. Is there a alternative?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf) the're id <iterate> element